# Adding & making a header and footer banner responsive

Tags: html, css

I have tried adding a header and footer banner but the banner doesn't look right and also isn't responsive. Here is my header code:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<header> 
  <center style="margin-top: 10px"><a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://example.com" alt="Banner"></a></center>
```

This is my footer code:

```html
<!--Footer-->
<center><a href="https://example.com" alt="Banner"></a></center>
<footer class="page-footer">
  <div class="container section">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m12 l6">
        <h5>
          <img src="{{ file_exists('assets/images/logo-udf.png') ? 'assets/images/logo-udf.png' : 'assets/images/logo.png' }}">
          <span>{{ @site.name }}</span>
        </h5>
        <p>
          {{ @site.description }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
        <h5><span>{{ @text.top_risers }}</span></h5>
        <ul>
          <repeat group="{{ @vars.risers }}" value="{{ @coin }}">
            <li><a href="{{ @BASE }}{{ 'coin','symbol='.@coin.symbol | alias }}">{{ @coin.name }}<span class="right">{{ @coin.change_pct }}</span></a></li>
          </repeat>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
        <h5><span>{{ @text.top_fallers }}</span></h5>
        <ul>
          <repeat group="{{ @vars.fallers }}" value="{{ @coin }}">
            <li><a href="{{ @BASE }}{{ 'coin','symbol='.@coin.symbol | alias }}">{{ @coin.name }}<span class="right">{{ @coin.change_pct }}</span></a></li>
          </repeat>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-copyright">
    <div class="container section">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m6">
          <a href="{{ @BASE }}/page/faq">{{ @text.faq_header }}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<!--END Footer-->
```

This website displays the top crypto coins and I wanted the banners to look good on all screen sizes. Both banners are 728X90 pixels.

Comment: Do you want the banners to fill the width of the screen?

Comment: Yes, but the banners are only 728X90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach this class to both banners. Like the example below.

```
<center style="margin-top: 10px"><a href="https://example.com"><img class="imgClass" src="https://example.com" alt="Banner"></a></center>
```

And in your stylesheet your Class should be.

```
 .imgClass{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  float:left;
  }
```

Inline would look like this

```
<img style="width:100%; height:auto; float:left;" class="imgClass" src="https://example.com" alt="Banner">
```

Comment: It is easy to scale a img down and keep its integrity, but scaling up is a different story. you can set a width and height for an image and if the ratio of that img isnt scaled the same it distorts or stretches.  Easiest route is to resize the image via photoshop or something to the right size

Comment: Hi Jonny, what CSS should I add if I just want the image to be responsive but stay 728x90 when viewed on a desktop/laptop? Also, how can I remove that small white gap on the header banner? Thanks so much man

Comment: do you have a link where i can view the img? and try taking away your top margin on your header.  might be your gap.

Comment: Ok, the banner is a fixed size.

Comment: You will probably have to create a banner around that size.  any image will stretch out with those ratios that is why i was asking for an img link

Comment: With the header on the url you provided you can work around this problem

Comment: I found a solution using the max-width tag in the CSS, it is responsive on the phones and stays at the original size on desktop mode.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.125);
}
.nav>.container {
    max-width: 950px;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.nav .title {
    display: inline-block
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #333;
}



/*** NOT RELEVANT ***/
html { height: 500px; background: #f9f9f9;
padding-top:60px;font-family:sans-serif;}
#app {margin-top:35px;}
.container {
    max-width: 950px;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
img {
max-width: 100%;}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />

<header class="nav" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="/" class="title">Brand</a>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container" id="app">
  <img src="https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/btc_value.png">
  <small><em>Image from Google Search</em></small>
</div>
```

If your just looking for something very simple (e.g. without navigation) you could simply do something like this.

**For CSS**

```
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.125);
}
.nav>.container {
    max-width: 950px;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.nav .title {
    display: inline-block
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #333;
}
```

**For HTML**

```
<header class="nav" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="/" class="title">Brand</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

**REMEMBER! To include the viewport tag.**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```